# Why/how does stress sometimes cause a spike in WBC or even a fever?

Tags: physiology, stress, psychosomatic-illness, white-blood-count

I've noticed a direct correlation between a spike in my WBC (when I don't have an detection of a viral or bacterial infection) and sometimes (but pretty rare for me), an elevated body-temperature that becomes a fever.

Over a course of months, my doctors have been monitoring my WBC and I've been monitoring my temperature, and a pattern we have noticed is that everything elevates when I'm under academic stress -- I'm a PhD student taking Comprehensive Exams (not in a medical related field, obviously).

**But -- Why/how does stress sometimes cause a spike in WBC or even a fever?** *Do either of these psychosomatic symptoms ever work in our benefit of calming us down under stress?*

Comment: Cortisol commonly raises wbc eg when taking Prednisone or under stress.